# C# string manipulation search and replace

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string which contain tags in the form `< tag >`. Is there an easy way for me to programmatically replace instances of these tags with special ascii characters? e.g. replace a tag like `"< tab >"` with the ascii equivelent of `'/t'`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string s = "...<tab>...";
s = s.Replace("<tab>", "\t");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex.Replace(s, "TAB", "\t");//s is your string and TAB is a tab.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex("< tab >", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static string regexReplace = "\t";
string result = regex.Replace(InputText,regexReplace);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex patterns should do the trick.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Expresso http://ultrapico.com to guide me through the tough ones.