# Substitution inside verbatim string literals?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In relation with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176229/what-is-the-best-practice-for-writing-sql-queries-inside-c-code) about how to write long SQL queries within C#., the solution suggested that a long sql query should be written as:

```
string query = @"
    SELECT
        c.CUSTOMER_ID,
        COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, ''_ + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME
        ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE
    FROM
        CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ct INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c
            ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID
    ";
```

That makes me curious about another related question. Can I use substitution somehow? That is, how would I manage if say the table name changes but the query remains the same? Do I have to fall back to using the other approach of building a string using string concatenations or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why not make use of string.Format?   In the specific example you gave, you could do something like

```
string query = @"
SELECT
    c.CUSTOMER_ID,
    COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, ''_ + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME
    ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE
FROM
    {0} AS ct INNER JOIN {1} AS c
        ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID
";
```

And the invoke

```
string real_query = string.Format(query, tblName1, tblName2);
```

Comment: That is a great response, and idea.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the String.Format method.

```
string custtype = "CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE";
string cust = "CUSTOMER"; 
string query = @"
SELECT
    c.CUSTOMER_ID,
    COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, ''_ + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME
    ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE
FROM
    {0} AS ct INNER JOIN {1} AS c
        ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID
"; 

string endQuery = String.Format(query, custtype, cust);
```

The String.Format method will replace the parameters identified by {x} sequentially with the arguments following the string, so {0} will be replaced with the value of custtype, and {1} with the value of cust.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using LINQ to SQL, if you haven't already.

Answering the actual question, you could use `string.Format` as the others have mentioned if you're creating the query. If you wish to modify an existing string, try using `string.Replace` or `Regex.Replace` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94342/c-string-manipulation-search-and-replace). That is:

```
string query = @"
    SELECT
        c.CUSTOMER_ID,
        COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, ''_ + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME
        ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE
    FROM
        CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ct INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c
            ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID
    ";
query.Replace("CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE", "NEW_TABLE_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpolated verbatim string

```
string filter = "name LIKE '%volvo%'";
string strSQL = $@"
    SELECT  code, name
    FROM    tb_car
    WHERE   {filter}
    ";
```